# Show image with Ajax and beforeSend

Tags: jquery

I am relative new to jquery and ajax, and I am amazed about the possibilities!

I am working on my first ajax, jquery (with validation plugin) webform. It's almost done, but a little thing I do not understand. I want to show a loading icon and disable the sending button with the beforeSend method. But it does not work and chrome does not show any error messages.

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Formular").validate({
    rules: {
        name: "required",
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        yname: "required",
        yemail: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }  
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        theUrl = 'send.php';
        var params = $(form).serialize();
        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: theUrl,
            data: params,
            beforeSend : function(){
                $('.loading_icon').show();
            },              
            processData: false,
            async: false,
            success: function(response) {
                $('#response').hide();
                $('#response').html(response);
                $('#response').fadeIn('slow');
                $('.loading_icon').hide();  
            }
        });
    }
});
```

});

The loading Icon does not show up. It worked before the submitHandler, so the css is right and the image also.

Here the part which does not anything:

```
                beforeSend : function(){
                $('.loading_icon').show();
            },
```

I searched here and in the documentation also, but I did not found any solution. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is it possible for us to get an fiddle demonstrating your problem, easier for us to play around with.

Comment: why you used `processData :false`. any specific reason?

Comment: I am new to ajax and jquery, so I try to work with tutorials and this is copied code, so in fact I do not know why I used processData ... sorry.. need to search the tut again, I read so many

Comment: The formular does not any captchas at the moment, so I add the link this way, please remove the '+'   ht+tp://+kids.yaqiin.net+/TEST/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the JQuery documentation says:

> A pre-request callback function that can be used to modify the jqXHR
>   (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object before it is sent. Use this
>   to set custom headers, etc. The jqXHR and settings maps are passed as
>   arguments. This is an Ajax Event. Returning false in the beforeSend
>   function will cancel the request. As of jQuery 1.5, the beforeSend
>   option will be called regardless of the type of request

Which makes me think it shouldn't be used for something like a loading icon. Why don't you just:

```
var params = $(form).serialize();
$('.loading_icon').show();       
 $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: theUrl,
            data: params,             
            processData: false  
        }).done(function(response) {
            $('#response').hide();
            $('#response').html(response);
            $('#response').fadeIn('slow');
        }).always(function() {
          $('.loading_icon').hide();
        });
```

**EDIT**

I've debugged the code using Firebug, works fine. It's just your post is so fast you never see it.

**Edit**
updates to use jqXHR object for success,etc. Removed `async:false` as this should never be used...

Comment: thank you, the uploaded code is at the moment like you said, but it does not give me a error message nor the icon shows up... I remember I tried it before this way (sorry not sure had been trying so many different ways)

Comment: Not sure then, if you provide a fiddle I might be able to help?

Comment: thank you! Sure, here the link (please remove the + since it has no captcha at the moment) ht+tp://+kids.yaqiin.net+/TEST/

Comment: The validation plugin is active, the fields named "sähköposti" and the * need an email adress.. sorry if this causes trouble with testing

Comment: @kaktus, add comment above. If you debug it using firebug you can see the image showing but it disappears before it has time to load.

Comment: thank you so much!! I wondered why it does not show anything! Sorry, never thought it could be such a problem...

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to let the loading icon appear right at the click of the send button? Like this it takes few seconds when the ajax process is going on, and then it can be seen, but thats too late... ?

Answer (score 2):

It is not true that it loads so fast that you don't see the wheel. Actually, when you add consecutively a css change and a sync ajax request, the change is delayed until the request is done in some browsers, like Chrome. Look in your ajax calls:

```
async: false,
```

The problem during sync ajax calls while debugging is that the debugger itself allows the full execution of each method before stopping, changing what you see in the end. So setting up a breakpoint in any line of a code like this:

```
$('.loading_icon').show();       
$.ajax ({something});
```

It will show the loading icon. Be very careful with that! Because when you don't set any breakpoint, the loading icon will not show until the result happens (success, error).

The only way that I have found to work properly in this kind of situation is to transform the sync call in ajax into an async one. If you are afraid that you will allow the user to touch something inappropriate during the process, just add a div over the whole page and disable any click events through it. Do it in this way and you will find that the loading icon appears during the whole ajax request, and not only at its end.