# How do i show a GIF loading image before jquery success() is execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, gif

I'm updating my form with lots of data so that I need to set **loading GiF image** so that user can understand that data is inserting to db.

I'm using following jquery. Can you guys tell me how can I show this loading image before **success()** is execute ?

loadubg.gif (it's my loading image)

```
$('body').on('click', '#upload', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]);

    var cid=$('#cdid').val();



    $.ajax({
        url: 'editContactDetails.php',
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            return myXhr;
        },
        success: function(data){                    
          // getDetails(cid);
          $("#success").html(data);
            document.getElementById("all_contact_details").reset();


        },
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

Comment: Before the  $.ajax code show whatever image you want to be shown. On success hide it. It's really not difficult.

Comment: You prob want to hide it on always not complete

Comment: @Liam Thanks for your quick reply...is it something like that `$("#loading-image").hide();` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069184/show-image-with-ajax-and-beforesend  , plz search stackoverflow before posting a duplicate question

Comment: Yes, it's that simple. It does depend where your image is in the pages, etc. but anything like that. Like I said use always not success then it will hide even if your call fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just show the loading image before the call to `$.ajax`.

Create a div or img tag for your loading image, and set it to display:none.

```
<img src="loading.gif" id="loading" style="display:none"/>
```

and modify your script like this

```
$('body').on('click', '#upload', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    $("#loading").show(); //show loading
    var formData = new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]);

    var cid=$('#cdid').val();



    $.ajax({
        url: 'editContactDetails.php',
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            return myXhr;
        },
        success: function(data){                    
          // getDetails(cid);
          $("#success").html(data);
            document.getElementById("all_contact_details").reset();

        },
        complete: function(){
          $("#loading").hide(); //hide loading here
        },
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm trying your code now..

Comment: Great It's working fine. You are provided my nice solution with example id. Great.

Comment: @Babu check the updated code. It uses `.complete`, which hides loading even when the ajax request fails. Also you can use `.always` as well for hiding the div

Answer (score 3):

Use [AjaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstart/) and [AjaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) callbacks:

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  $( ".loading" ).show();
});

$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $( ".loading" ).hide();
});
```

If you don't wan global callbacks, you can put these into the `$.ajax` call:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    beforeSend: function(){$( ".loading" ).show();},
    complete: function(){$( ".loading" ).hide();}
    ...
});
```

Also, everyone else are suggesting you to hide the gif in `success` handler. This is incorrect. If an ajax call results in an error, your gif will keep on spinning. `complete` handler is the correct place to do that.

Comment: Ok, people suggest this a lot. But for me it's opening a can of beans using dynamite. This will **always** show the image on **every** ajax call. Not what everyone wants.

Comment: I've updated the answer, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Show images just before ajax call starts and hide it after it completes. (assuming GIF image has `id="gifImage"`

```
$('body').on('click', '#upload', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]);

    var cid=$('#cdid').val();


    $('#gifImage').show();// show image here
    $.ajax({
        url: 'editContactDetails.php',
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            return myXhr;
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          $('#gifImage').hide();// hide image here
        },
        success: function(data){                    
          // getDetails(cid);
         $('#gifImage').hide();// hide image here
          $("#success").html(data);
            document.getElementById("all_contact_details").reset();


        },
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

Comment: This way, if an ajax call results in an error, the gif will keep on spinning.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best way is to set your #success div to show the gif image, as soon as the #upload is clicked.

Then the success method will overwrite the gif once it is finished:

```
$('body').on('click', '#upload', function(e){

    // SHOW IMAGE AS SOON AS AJAX STARTS
    $("#success").html("<img src="loadubg.gif></img>");

    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]);

    var cid=$('#cdid').val();



    $.ajax({
        url: 'editContactDetails.php',
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            return myXhr;
        },
        success: function(data){                    
          // getDetails(cid);

          // ONCE AJAX REQUEST FINISHED, OVERWRITE THE GIF IMAGE
          $("#success").html(data);

          document.getElementById("all_contact_details").reset();


        },
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Show loading image before calling jQuery.ajax(). Let's say you have a imageDiv to show that image. Use following :

```
$("#imageDiv").html('<img src = "loadubg.gif">');
$("#imageDiv").show();
$.ajax({
    url: 'editContactDetails.php',
    type: 'POST',
    xhr: function() {
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        return myXhr;
    },
    success: function(data){                    
      // getDetails(cid);
      $("#success").html(data);
        document.getElementById("all_contact_details").reset();
           $("#imageDiv").hide();

    },
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

call your script/function to show your loader during the process, and hide your loader after the process is complete.

```
beforeSend: function(){
  //show img loader
},
complete: function(){
  //hide img loader
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Div in your HTML file

```
<div class="ajax-loader"></div>
```

and  then add 2 new parameter in ur ajax call. Beforesend and Complete

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'editContactDetails.php',
    type: 'POST',
    xhr: function() {
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        return myXhr;
    },    
    beforeSend: function() {
        $(".ajax-loader").html("<img src="images/loader_image.gif">");
    },
    complete: function(){
        $(".ajax-loader").html("");
    },
    success: function(data){                    
      // getDetails(cid);
      $("#loading").hide(); //hide loading
      $("#success").html(data);
        document.getElementById("all_contact_details").reset();


    },
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```